# How to query current row's DB name in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

TableA exists in all 4 DBs, run this,

```
Use DB1
go
select CurrentDB=DB_NAME(), * From DB1..TableA union all
select CurrentDB=DB_NAME(), * From DB2..TableA union all
select CurrentDB=DB_NAME(), * From DB3..TableA union all
select CurrentDB=DB_NAME(), * From DB4..TableA
```

always got CurrentDB ='DB1'. is there a **Simple** way to get DB2,3,4 when the rows are pulling from non-DB1? 
Trying to **avoid hard code**.

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't just do Select 'DB1, * From Db1.... Union all select 'DB2',... etc?

Comment: @Tony. I could, just thought someone might know a less 'hard-coded' version.

Comment: Less hard coded?? Hard coding is not a precentage, it is either is or it isn't. You already have to put in the database to pull from. Just type in the name and be done with it. There are other ways to do this but it doesn't provide much, if any, benefit.

Comment: Have a look at sp_msforeachdb, or you could do a cursor, but seeing as you've already hard-coded in the from clause I fail to see the point.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable idea to minimize the number of references to the database name if it were possible to do that. Unfortunately it's not.

Comment: I would accept an answer, even the answer may be:  No. No simple, Non-hardcoded way.

Comment: In my opinion, if you use the full qualified name, which is hard-coding, you can hard-code also the database name. If you use synonyms instead (without indicating the fully qualified name, but applying the [schema].[object] two part name) you can avoid the usage of the DB* prefix, but you cannot point to a relative DB_NAME() value, since this function returns the CURRENT database name (the session database name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the same view in each database that returns the value of `DB_NAME()` as a column. Then, in the union, the each row will include the database name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Use Master
set NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @db_name Varchar(12)
Declare @sql Varchar(1000)

Declare db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT [name]
  FROM sys.databases Where [name] like 'DB[123456789]'

Open db_cursor

Fetch Next FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name
if @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  Select @sql = 'select ''' + @db_name + ''', * From ' + @db_name + '..TableA'
  Fetch Next FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name
  While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin
    select @sql = @sql + ' Union all select ''' + 
           @db_name + ''', * From ' +   @db_name + '..TableA'
    Fetch NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name
  end
  exec @sql
end
Close db_cursor
Deallocate db_cursor
```

Not tested, but basic idea is get all the matching db names. Build the sql statement, then exec it.